# How to load quantized LLM to CPU only device?

Tags: large-language-model, huggingface, gpt-3

I have this code to quantize a large language model and save the quantized model:

```
import torch
from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, AutoTokenizer, BitsAndBytesConfig

model_name = 'stabilityai/stablelm-2-zephyr-1_6b'

def load_quantized_model(model_name: str):
    bnb_config = BitsAndBytesConfig(
        load_in_4bit=True,
        bnb_4bit_use_double_quant=True,
        bnb_4bit_quant_type="nf4",
        bnb_4bit_compute_dtype=torch.bfloat16
    )
    model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
        model_name,
        load_in_4bit=True,
        torch_dtype=torch.bfloat16,
        quantization_config=bnb_config,
        trust_remote_code=True
    )
    return model

def initialize_tokenizer(model_name: str):
    tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(
        model_name,
        trust_remote_code=True
    )
    tokenizer.bos_token_id = 1  # Set beginning of sentence token id
    return tokenizer

model = load_quantized_model(model_name)
tokenizer = initialize_tokenizer(model_name)

SAVED_MODEL_NAME = 'quantized'
model.save_pretrained(SAVED_MODEL_NAME)
```

Now, I have a 1.2GB (from ~4gb) model inside the directory gpt-custom.

So I download it in my laptop with CPU only and this is my code:

```
import torch
from transformers import AutoModelForCausalLM, AutoTokenizer, BitsAndBytesConfig

model_name = 'stabilityai/stablelm-2-zephyr-1_6b'

model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
    'quantized',
    device_map="auto",
    trust_remote_code=True
)

def initialize_tokenizer(model_name: str):
    tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(
        model_name,
        trust_remote_code=True
    )
    tokenizer.bos_token_id = 1  # Set beginning of sentence token id
    return tokenizer

tokenizer = initialize_tokenizer(model_name)

question = 'how are you feeling?'
prompt = [{'role': 'user', 'content': question}]
inputs = tokenizer.apply_chat_template(
    prompt,
    add_generation_prompt=True,
    return_tensors='pt'
)
tokens = model.generate(
    inputs.to(model.device),
    max_new_tokens=64,
    temperature=0.5,
    do_sample=True
)
print(tokenizer.decode(tokens[0], skip_special_tokens=True))
```

But I am getting an error `NameError: name 'torch' is not defined` but I already installed torch using `pip install torch` and even tried `pip install --upgrade torch`. There was also this warning before the error:

```
Detected the presence of a `quantization_config` attribute in the model's configuration but you don't have the correct `bitsandbytes` version to support 4 and 8 bit serialization. Please install the latest version of `bitsandbytes` with  `pip install --upgrade bitsandbytes`.
```

And I have also tried `pip install --upgrade bitsandbytes` but still get the same error.

This is the full error stack:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/html/test_llm/test.py", line 6, in <module>
    model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/models/auto/auto_factory.py", line 562, in from_pretrained
    return model_class.from_pretrained(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/modeling_utils.py", line 3856, in from_pretrained
    ) = cls._load_pretrained_model(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/modeling_utils.py", line 4290, in _load_pretrained_model
    new_error_msgs, offload_index, state_dict_index = _load_state_dict_into_meta_model(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/modeling_utils.py", line 839, in _load_state_dict_into_meta_model
    set_module_quantized_tensor_to_device(model, param_name, param_device, value=param)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/transformers/integrations/bitsandbytes.py", line 58, in set_module_quantized_tensor_to_device
    if old_value.device == torch.device("meta") and device not in ["meta", torch.device("meta")] and value is None:
NameError: name 'torch' is not defined
```

Comment: you save your quantized model as `gpt-custom` but load it as `quantized`... the first argument of `.load_pretrained` is the models path or name... in the online docs there is no model `quantized` and it does not match your model, too

Comment: also, this is not a issue of torch installation, as the error is raised after some internal `torch.device` checks that I dont understand so far...

Comment: @Klops thanks for the response. sorry, yes, my model was saved as `quantized` and the folder name is also `quantized`.